# Trying to remove all text within Parentheses and remove parentheses as well as well as Turn all the capital letters except Except the first letter

Tags: google-sheets, parentheses

I have a google sheet with a list of names that I am trying to apply my existing formula to. There are some names that have parentheses with text within those parentheses as well as some names that are all captial letters. I want to remove the parentheses and the text within as well having only the first letter of each name capitalized written into a formula. My existing formula removes the parenthese, dashes and quotation marks which I want to keep it that way, but now I am just wantint to add onto that formula all together for what I stated above. I will also link my practice google sheet so you can see where I am applying the formula.

Formula: =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(C4:C411,"-|'|,|(|)|"""," ")))

[Practice Formula Sheet](https://https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qv7iXj8AbM4khLEfLJgmCnL1Z4c87wBtcHEgt6I3dL4/edit#gid=0)

[If the doc is not accessible here is photo of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3hia.jpg)

I was trying to use an older version of this formula i.e: =REGEXREPLACE(C4:C411,"([^()]*)","").
This does remove the parentheses with the text inside as well but thats it. I need to remove the parentheses as well as the text within those parentheses and the names that are all captial letters. I want to remove the parentheses and the text within as well having only the first letter of each name capitalized written into a formula.

Comment: link to the sheet is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"\(.*?\)",""),"[^\w\s]"," "))))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: That worked! I looked everywhere to see what I was doing wrong. I am still very new at google sheet formulas so thank you for your help! If you do not mind explaining what [^\w\s] does I would appreciate that. That seems to be the main thing that changed along with adding Proper

Comment: [^\w\s]=anything other than words and space

Comment: Perfect thank you! One last thing I noticed and I do not know if this is possible. In this list there are names such as (William Bill"") that have double quotation marks indicating a nick name for that person. In the formula you helped me with is there a way to add into that formula that essentially finds anything with those double quotation marks and deletes the name associated with it? i.e. (William Bill" - William)

Comment: try: =ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(G2:G15,"\(.*?\)",""),"(\w+"")",""),"[^\w\s]"," "))))

Comment: That did work for removing the double quotation marks but it seem to revert a few things such as: William (Bill) is now William Bill. Whereas the one you had originally made it so it went from William (Bill) to William.

Comment: (https://i.imgur.com/2Cg4Ztx.png) The backslashes are auto-removed or interpreted differently when I gave the formula above via comment section.

Comment: Oh yes! Now I see it! That worked! Thank you! This has fully answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A25:A28, 
 "['-]", " "), "[^A-Za-z ]", )))
```

[image]

you can add PROPER, LOWER or UPPER if you need so:

```
=INDEX(PROPER(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A25:A28, 
 "['-]", " "), "[^A-Za-z ]", ))))
```